# How to set watchers on Realm model?

Tags: swift, realm

For debugging purposes, I would like to set watchers/observers on models but I didn't find hint so far.

Notice I'm rather new in iOS development (less than a month) so I might be missing something.

Comment: Have you tried using Realm Browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to observe a whole class of objects, you can make a query, apply filters and then observe these `Results` for [Notifications](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#notifications).

If you want to observe changes to a single object, you can retrieve it and then observe the properties you're interested in via [Key-Value Observation (KVO)](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#key-value-observation).

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example on KVO in Realm (Swift):
Just for demonstration on how KVO i Realm with persistent objects work.

```
class MyRealmClass: Object {
    dynamic var id = NSUUID().UUIDString
    dynamic var date: NSDate?
    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    } 
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var myObject: MyRealmClass?

    private var myContext = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        myObject = MyRealmClass()
        try! uiRealm.write({ () -> Void in
            myObject?.date = NSDate()
            uiRealm.add(myObject!, update: true)
            print("New MyClass object initialized with date property set to \(myObject!.date!)")
        })

        myObject = uiRealm.objects(MyRealmClass).last
        myObject!.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "date", options: .New, context: &myContext)

        //Sleep before updating the objects 'date' property.
        NSThread.sleepForTimeInterval(5)

        //Update the property (this will trigger the observeValueForKeyPath(_:object:change:context:) method)
        try! uiRealm.write({ () -> Void in
            myObject!.date = NSDate()
        })
    }

    override func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String?, ofObject object: AnyObject?, change: [String : AnyObject]?, context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) {
        if context == &myContext {
            print("Date property has changed, new value is \(change![NSKeyValueChangeNewKey]!)")
        }
    }
 }
```